# Changing namespace in SOAP message using jax rpc soap message handler

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

I am trying to alter the namespace for a element in a soap request using saaj api in a jax-rpc soap message handler.

For eg:

```
<\s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
<\s:Body>
   <\ns2:getAllGeneratedPasswords\>xmlns:ns2="http://service.services.manufacturing.evse.inds.ge.com/">
          <\ps1:userType xmlns="ps1:http://sdsdf.asdasd">user<\/ps1:userType>
        <\/ns2:getAllGeneratedPasswords>
      <\/s:Body>
<\/s:Envelope>
```

In the above soap request, I want to change:

> xmlns:ns2="http://service.services.manufacturing.evse.inds.ge.com/"

to

> xmlns:ns2="http://service.company.com/"

```
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.GenericHandler
import....
import...

public class ServiceHandler extends GenericHandler{

    public boolean handleRequest(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        //manipulate namespace here
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of exception you are getting..

Comment: I am not getting any exception. Its just that I need a way to change namespace in handler